# How do I extract a web page completely with its dependencies inlined, and images converted to dataURI?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I have a page that I want to download.

It has over 50 images, I could go and download them all. 
But is there a tool that would take the `url`, and give one single `html` file with all images, and `js` inlined?

Comment: You can't do web scraping with client-side `JavaScript` only, you need a server-side proxy to be able to access cross-domain resources.

Comment: any language can be server side if you run it on a server

(nodejs)

Comment: I dont really need to scrap site, i just need to download page as a whole.

Comment: I dont want to rely on their site as their links will change and break, i want this to be isolated one page with as much as of its resources in it. i could manually do it, but it'd be great if there is a site that does it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use wget to download webpage with all it's assets (this won't be single file but will not depend on external resources)

or this browser extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-mhtml/eomfifclcdpkaghkehajpolkdnkmegfa?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

What about this? 
https://www.httrack.com/
I used it several time and it works great.